# Acessar função do controller pela diretiva

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

ola a pergunta e simples tenho um botao na minha diretiva que e claro ja tem um ng-click("alterardata();") a regra e que o controller que chame essa diretiva tenha essa função por padrao mas o problema e que clico no botao e nao funciona coloquei outro botao na pagina principal e esse funciona

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um *callback* (em português, *chamada de retorno*).

Na sua diretiva, defina uma propriedade de escopo que receberá o *callback* do *controller*:

```
app.directive('exemploDiretiva', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<h3>Olá!</h3>',
        scope: {
            chamadaCallback: '&' // <- Define uma referência de função externa
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

Isso feito, defina o valor na *view*:

```
<exemplo-diretiva chamada-callback="meuMetodoDoController(arg1)"></exemplo-diretiva>
```

> Perceba que, enquanto que a definição é feita no formato `camelCase` (`chamadaCallback`), a parametrização deve ser feita em formato `lowercase-dash` (`chamada-callback`).

Com isso feito, crie o método `meuMetodoDoController` no *controller* - ele será invocado quando, na diretiva, você invocar o callback da seguinte maneira:

```
scope.chamadaCallback('qualquerParametroQueVoceQuiser');
```

Comment: acho que estou quase la esta dando esse erro TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'alterarPeriodo' in 1 no template comtem(ng-click="funcaoPeriodo(0)"), na directive de nome painel contem (funcaoPeriodo: "&"), na pagina principal contem <painel funcao-periodo="alterarPeriodo()"></painel>

Comment: Em funcao-periodo="alterarPeriodo()" Você está passando o resultado da função. Ao invés disso, tente funcao-periodo="alterarPeriodo".

Comment: ja tentei e da o mesmo erro ainda nao sei oq fazer :?